# Spring Security CORS

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have tried to create endpoints and access those of them that don't need a role, but my Spring Security configuration wouldn't allow me to use it because of CORS.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/getChecks").hasAuthority(Permission.USERS_READ.getPermission())
            .antMatchers("/addCheck").hasAuthority(Permission.USERS_ADD_DOTES.getPermission())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(jwtConfigurer);
}
```

Should I add some additional configuration in SecurityConfig.java?

I want to access the endpoint.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `cors().and()` to the configuration before `csrf().disable()`